# after publishing website, Internal URL did not work

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, umbraco

I design a website by Umbraco. Before that I published it. All everything was OK.
But after publishing, link to internal webPages did not work.

befor publishing:
    "http://localhost:4402/testgroup/testgroup01/testitem01.aspx?nodeId=1400"

after publishing:
    "http://localhost/testgroup/testgroup01/testitem01.aspx?nodeId=1400"

I do not konw what to do..
PLEASE HELP ME.

Note:
In code behind, at the beginning of href tag, added "/.." or "/~" or "~" but did not work.
All "" created dynamically by HtmlGenericControl
[image: My website name in IIS is NAMAAD]
[image: Error Page after publish]

Comment: Make sure you have configured proper virtual directory in the IIS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it!

I create a website in IIS in "Sites" node.(already exist in "Default Web Site"). and I gave a port for website (for example 5050).

It be solved.

Thank you from all of you that try to solve my problem.

[image: You can see it.]

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the bindings in the advanced settings of your website at the IIS to this:

```
http::4402:
```

Comment: I set Enabled Protocols to "http::4402:", but it didn't work.       IIS advance setting -> virtual path is /NAMAAD

Comment: Then I'm absolutely clueless for the moment. I'm sorry

Answer (score 0):

Provide that code, the way you link to the pages in your ".cs"

Answer (score 0):

If virtual path is `/NAMAAD` then use the `http://localhost/NAMAAD/` as a base and go down to the page you need.

Also, I cannot see the folders `testgroup` or `testgroup01` in the `NAMAAD`, check where exactly is the page you want.